# ASP.NET MVC: What's the difference in concept between Service and Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The question I'm asking is kind of subjective. I've seen twice, while exercising with real projects such as StoreFront, both Repository and Services. Sometimes they can just be folders or projects attached to the solution. But they contain classes and interfaces.

So, I'd like to know what goes to the repository and what goes to the services. So far, I was familiar with repositories (we put methods and properties in the repository to reduce the complexity in the controller). **How about the services?**

So, ASP.NET MVC: What's the difference in concept between Service and Repository? (Maybe none)

My question is Kind of subjective, but I'd like to make sure that I'm not missing anything.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, the repository simply provides an interface to data.  There is no application logic there.  Services provide interfaces to application logic.  Services often use repositories.

Comment: @Richard77: Services use repositories for data access.  The repository's only purpose is to hide the details of data access.  For example, my current application has a ShipmentNotificationService that  wraps up all the logic required to send tracking number and shipment cost information to front-end systems we interface with.  It uses several repositories to access the database.

Comment: @Richard77: Go look at Sharp Architecture (http://sharparchitecture.net/) for some practical guidance in the form of a sample application.  They do a really good job of separating controller, repository and service for ASP.NET MVC. You can uses Sharp Architecture for the basis of your project if you would like to also try an ORM.

Comment: Cabansky: I like your answer and will follow the link to SharpArchitecture